# PHP mPDF library won't number even/odd pages properly

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm trying to do some PDF generation in PHP. I found mPDF which generally has worked quite well. One problem I'm having though is that I need to be able to set separate headers for even/odd pages for some sections. I don't think the function is working right. Here's my code:

```
// load mPDF
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
include('mpdf.php');
$mpdf = new mPDF();

// generate a lot of content so it spans multiple pages
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
$i = 0;
$out = '';
while ($i < 300)
{
    $i++;
    $out .= '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
}
// set html header for odd pages, write html and output
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('ODD {PAGENO}', 'O');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($out);
$mpdf->Output();
```

When I run this code it puts "ODD Page 3" or whatever page it's on... on every page. Not just the odd pages. It seems to not consider naturally broken pages as new pages for the purposes of even or odd, only manually broken ones. If I run the **AddPage()** function it will consider the next group an even page. But that could be 50 auto page breaks later.

Any suggestions on how to get it to set different headers for *actual* even/odd pages, not just after manual page breaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your forget to write

`$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 1;`

here is your working example

```
<?php
include("../mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4'); 
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 1 ;// Use different Odd/Even headers and footers and mirror margins

// generate a lot of content so it spans multiple pages
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
$i = 0;
$out = '';
while ($i < 300)
{
    $i++;
    $out .= '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
}
// set html header for odd pages, write html and output
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('{PAGENO}/{nb}', 'O',true);
/* Note: SetHTMLHeader() and SetHTMLFooter() without a side(2nd argument) 
       - sets ODD page header/footer only as default..so you can also write just 
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('{PAGENO}/{nb}'); */
$mpdf->WriteHTML($out);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Reference:

**[setHTMLHeader](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=150)**